# I am having trouble setting up GTK+ with code blocks

Tags: c, gtk, codeblocks

I am trying to setup code blocks gtk+4 project. It first asked me to find where the gtk library is installed (I installed it with msys64 if that helps). After i located where, this is where my problems starts to arise. Code blocks asked me to setup the directory of the location of the gtk on my computer. The prompt also told me that where exactly the folder is must contain the sub-folders "include" and "lib".

So i set the GTK's location to "C:\msys64\mingw64" it contains both "include" and "lib". I expected to be done, and I could continue with what i was doing. But instead i get this error "The path you entered seems valid, but this wizard can't locate the following GTK's include file: gtk.h".

With that i went to see where gtk.h is located. "C:\msys64\mingw64\include\gtk-4.0\gtk" one of the few first things in that folder ordered by name. I thought i would be done after setting it but now i get this error "The path you entered seems valid, but the wizard can't locate the include directory. The wizard cannot continue.

And with that i am out of ideas to be honest, As i do not know what this program wants.